# Print custom MeshStandardMaterial in THREE.js

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I am trying to implement new custom features to the MeshStandardMaterial, in particular I would like to add the possibility to add two normal map that use different UV sets. Then I will combine them inside the fragment shader.

So far I have "doubled" meshstandardmaterial and make WebGLProgram insert keyword like "Use NormalMap2". The next step would be to mess around with actual glsl code.

Is there some way to print fragment shader or some how look what has been passed to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to debug my code was to use [webGL inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webgl-inspector/ogkcjmbhnfmlnielkjhedpcjomeaghda), it shows me what texture has been passed to the shader and also it shows me all shader code

Comment: Also consider [Shader Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shader-editor/ggeaidddejpbakgafapihjbgdlbbbpob).

Comment: I add here the link to github repo with [documentation](https://github.com/spite/ShaderEditorExtension) as well